# Google Charts in Sharepoint webpart

Tags: web-part, chart-web-part

Before begin, I tested the following code on a C# project "not SharePoint related" and it works, I know *a little* about Sharepoint webpart development, but I don't understand why this code doesn't works in the webpart that I'm doing...

**EDIT**: script API added.:

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

I'm facing the following issue:

I'm developing a farm solution webpart that generates ***dynamically*** a Column Chart or a Pie Chart (according to selection of one of ListItem in RadioButtonList):

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbt_graphicType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbt_graphicType_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Meeting Type" Selected="True" /> <!--Column Chart-->
    <asp:ListItem Text="Meeting Category" /> <!--Pie Chart-->
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

*When I say dynamically, I mean, I build Javascript code in a method and I call it in Page_Load event.*

The javascript generated will be contained in the Panel control called "pnl_data" and the chart will be in "chart_div" div element.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_data" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<div id="chart_div">
</div>
<asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server" />
```

The code-behind is *simple* (in my opinion).

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Page_Load.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateChart();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SelectedIndexChanged event for call "GenerateChart" method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void rbt_graphicType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateChart();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called in Page_Load.
    /// Generate a chart according to RadioButtonList selection.
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateChart()
    {
        try
        {
            //Initialize variables.
            string built_js = ""; //The "built_js" variable will hold the js generated in the folowing lines of code.
            HtmlGenericControl html_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            pnl_data.Controls.Clear();

            if (rbt_graphicType.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                //Build js code for generate Column Chart.
                built_js += "  \n  google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['columnchart'] });   \n";
                built_js += "  \n";
                built_js += "    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  \n";
                built_js += "  \n";
                built_js += "    function drawChart() {  \n";
                built_js += "        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  \n";
                built_js += "                  ['Tipo de reunión No.1 33.5%', 'Tipo de reunión No.2 70%', 'Tipo de reunión No.3 58%', 'Tipo de reunión No.4 82%', 'Tipo de reunión No.5 44%'],   \n";
                built_js += "                  [33.5, '', '', '', ''],     \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', 70, '', '', ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', 58, '', ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', '', 82, ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', '', '', 44]        \n";
                built_js += "                ]);  \n";
                built_js += "   \n";
                built_js += "        var options = {   \n";
                built_js += "            width: 600,   \n";
                built_js += "            height: 300,   \n";
                built_js += "            is3D: true,   \n";
                built_js += "            title: '" + dd_salas.SelectedItem.Text + "',   \n";
                built_js += "            bar: { groupWidth: '20%' },   \n";
                built_js += "            legendFontSize: '10',   \n";
                built_js += "            min: 10,   \n";
                built_js += "            max: 100   \n";
                built_js += "        };   \n";
                built_js += "   \n";
                built_js += "        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));   \n";
                built_js += "        chart.draw(data, options);   \n";
                built_js += "    }   \n";

                //Show text for "check" which Chart was generated.
                MessageLabel.Text = "Column Chart generated.<br/>";
            }
            if (rbt_graphicType.Items[1].Selected)
            {
                //Build js code for generate Pie Chart.
                //...

                //Show text for "check" which Chart was generated.
                MessageLabel.Text = "Pie Chart generated.<br/>";
            }

            //Add javscript code to InnerHtml attribute and built the <script> tag correctly.
            html_js.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            html_js.InnerHtml = built_js;
            pnl_graficos.Controls.Add(html_js);
            html_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
        }
        catch { MessageLabel = "Error in the ''GenerateChart'' method."; }
    }
```

**EDIT**: The values of Charts may change according to selected item from DropDownList control (the items already has values and there's no point focused on DropDownList's items values) - my bad, I didn't added this code before the answer of @Rephistorch -.

**EDIT**: The javascript code for generate the charts might not be *elegant* but it's fully functional (I tested it in C# project - as I said at the beginning of my question - ).

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_selRoom" Text="Select the room" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="dd_rooms" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="Room 1" Selected="True" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Room 2" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Room 3" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Room 4" />
   <asp:ListItem Text="Room 5" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The results obtained in the webpart deployed when I executed it shows *only* the sample text added on "MessageLabel" control and the *Column Chart* generated correctly (*because the first element in the RadioButtonList is selected by default* - I checked too putting the second element selected as default and the same situation happens - ).

I checked the console browser and there's no warning or error about js generated, however, when the selection changes, the chart code "even when the page reloads" doesn't change (still the *Column Chart* but no rendering, the "chart_div" element is empty).

I can share the js generated (and the C# sample code full), but the code is in spanish and I'm trying make the question the best understandable that I can.

Comment: How are you adding the script to the page? I dont see any references on how you are injecting the js scripts.

Comment: @AmalHashim Edited the question "I didn't included in the question because as I said in resumen _the Column Chart is generated_ this is not related to missing code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some adjustments and using Google Chrome Console for debug at runtime the page, it shows that even when the selection of which chart generate changes, the Chart *Column or Pie* doesn't render at all (i.e there's no image) but *the code of the chart* does.

With this modified code, both, the 3D Column and Pie Charts now is rendering:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// OnPreRender.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        #region Sección que obtiene los valores válidos para mostrar el Pie Chart.

        DataTable data = GetRoomStadistics();

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration(
            "MyArrayData", "['RoomTypes', 'Percentaje']");

        ////Registrar las ítems dentro del arreglo de javascript "en el lado cliente".
        foreach (DataRow dataitem in data.Rows)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("MyArrayData",
                string.Format("['{0}', {1}]",
                dataitem["RoomTypes"],
                dataitem["Percentaje"]));
        }
        data = new DataTable();

        #endregion
        GenerateCharts();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Page_Load.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Get the rooms "fill DropDownList control".
            GetRooms();

            #region Code for obtain datatable with example data for generate the Pie Chart.

            DataTable data = GetRoomStadistics();

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration(
                "MyArrayData", "['RoomTypes', 'Percentaje']");

            ////Register items inside javascript array "client side".
            foreach (DataRow dataitem in data.Rows)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("MyArrayData",
                    string.Format("['{0}', {1}]",
                    dataitem["RoomTypes"],
                    dataitem["percentaje"]));
            }
            data = new DataTable();

            #endregion
        }
        GenerateCharts();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Obtener las salas y agregarlos como ítems del DropDownList.
    /// </summary>
    private void GetRooms()
    {
        //Put code for add ListItems to DroDownListItem.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determina el tipo de gráfica a Build.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void rbt_graphicType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateCharts();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mauricio Arias Olave.
    /// 19/11/2014.
    /// De acuerdo a la opción seleccionada en el RadioButtonList y al a sala seleccionada, se Buildá
    /// una gráfica que indica las estadísticas de la sala seleccionada.
    /// </summary>
    private void GenerateCharts()
    {
        try
        {
            //Inicializar variables.
            string built_js = "";
            HtmlGenericControl html_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
            pnl_data.Controls.Clear();

            //1.0
            if (rbt_graphicType.Items[0].Selected)
            {
                #region Build Column Chart.

                //Clean string before generate javascript code.
                built_js = "";

                built_js += "  \n  google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['columnchart'] });   \n";
                built_js += "  \n";
                built_js += "    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  \n";
                built_js += "  \n";
                built_js += "    function drawChart() {  \n";
                built_js += "        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  \n";
                built_js += "                  ['Meeting Type # 1 33.5%', 'Meeting Type # 2 70%', 'Meeting Type # 3 58%', 'Meeting Type # 4 82%', 'Meeting Type # 5 44%'],   \n";
                built_js += "                  [33.5, '', '', '', ''],     \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', 70, '', '', ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', 58, '', ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', '', 82, ''],       \n";
                built_js += "                  ['', '', '', '', 44]        \n";
                built_js += "                ]);  \n";
                built_js += "   \n";
                built_js += "        var options = {   \n";
                built_js += "            width: 600,   \n";
                built_js += "            height: 300,   \n";
                built_js += "            is3D: true,   \n";
                built_js += "            title: '" + dd_rooms.SelectedItem.Text + "',   \n";
                built_js += "            bar: { groupWidth: '20%' },   \n";
                built_js += "            legendFontSize: '10',   \n";
                built_js += "            min: 10,   \n";
                built_js += "            max: 100   \n";
                built_js += "        };   \n";
                built_js += "   \n";
                built_js += "        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));   \n";
                built_js += "        chart.draw(data, options);   \n";
                built_js += "    }   \n";

                #endregion
                MessageLabel.Text = "Column chart!";
            }
            if (rbt_graphicType.Items[1].Selected)
            {
                #region Build Pie Chart.

                //Clean string before generate javascript code.
                built_js = "";

                built_js += "  google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'] });   \n";
                built_js += "      function drawVisualization() {    \n";
                built_js += " \n";
                built_js += "   /''MyArrayData'': array declarated in server side.*/   \n";
                built_js += "   var ChartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(MyArrayData);   \n";
                built_js += " \n";
                built_js += "   /*Settings*/   \n";
                built_js += "   var ChartOptions = {   \n";
                built_js += "       'title': '" + dd_rooms.SelectedItem.Text + "',   \n";
                built_js += "       'titleTextStyle': { color: 'black', fontName: '\"Verdana\"', fontSize: 12 },   \n";
                built_js += "       'width': 350,   \n";
                built_js += "       'height': 350,   \n";
                built_js += "       'backgroundColor': 'white',   \n";
                built_js += "       'chartArea': { 'width': '90%', 'height': '70%' },   \n";
                built_js += "       'pieSliceText': 'percentage',   \n";
                built_js += "       'tooltip': { textStyle: { color: 'black', fontName: '\"Verdana\"', fontSize: 12} },   \n";
                built_js += "       /*'tooltip': { trigger: 'none' }, */ /*Ocultar tooltip*/   \n";
                built_js += "       'is3D': true,   \n";
                built_js += "       legend: 'bottom',   \n";
                built_js += "       /*pieStartAngle: 20*/   \n";
                built_js += "   };   \n";
                built_js += " \n";
                built_js += "   /*Draw the pie chart.*/   \n";
                built_js += "   new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).   \n";
                built_js += "       draw(ChartData, ChartOptions);   \n";
                built_js += "               }   \n";
                built_js += "               google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);   \n";

                #endregion
                MessageLabel.Text = "Pie chart!";
            }

            //Add <script> element to "pnl_data" element.
            html_js.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
            html_js.InnerHtml = built_js;
            pnl_data.Controls.Add(html_js);
            html_js = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageLabel.Text += "Error: " + ex.Message; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// sampleTable con los indicadores de las salas.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>DataTable.</returns>
    private DataTable GetRoomStadistics()
    {
        DataTable sampleTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            DataColumn col_RoomType = new DataColumn();
            col_RoomType.ColumnName = "RoomTypes";
            col_RoomType.DataType = typeof(System.String);

            DataColumn col_RoomPercentaje = new DataColumn();
            col_RoomPercentaje.ColumnName = "Percentaje";
            col_RoomPercentaje.DataType = typeof(System.String);

            sampleTable.Columns.Add(col_RoomType);
            sampleTable.Columns.Add(col_RoomPercentaje);

            sampleTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Meeting Type # 1", "33.5" });
            sampleTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Meeting Type # 2", "70" });
            sampleTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Meeting Type # 3", "58" });
            sampleTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Meeting Type # 4", "82" });
            sampleTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Meeting Type # 5", "44" });

            return sampleTable;
        }
        catch { return sampleTable; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// SelectedIndexChanged.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void dd_rooms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GenerateCharts();
    }
```

A close view to the code, I'm not using any SPLisItem, SPQuery and/or similar SharePoint class for obtain data *(I omitted it because this isn't part of the main scope of my question).*

There's a short description about which steps I follow for get this results:

1. Call **GenerateChart()** method in (*OnPreRender*, *PageLoad* and *SelectedIndexChanged*) methods.
2. In **Page_Load** method, the call to **GenerateChart()** method must be *outside* of condtional *IsPostBack*.

*I don't know if this is the best approach for generate charts dynamically* but anyone can modify this code for your purpose.

Also, in Internet Explorer, the 3D Column Chart doesn't render. *I know that columnchart* is [deprecated](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart_old) but it works if:

1. Open F12 Developer Tool.
2. Change **Document Mode** that stays *standard* to **Internet Explorer 7 Standard.**

I think that there's some *cleaner* way for get similar or betters results, but, for the scope of my question this is an accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Google's `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` event in your javascript, try using `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("drawChart");`.

My theory is that by the time Google's API has loaded, your page's DOM has not been fully built, and so there is no "chart_div" to access.

Sidenote: I would recommend using the StringBuilder class instead of all of that concatenation.  It has nothing to do with your problem, but doing an `AppendLine("...")` is easier than putting `\n` everywhere. Feel free to ignore this if you want.

Comment: Agreed with _unnecessary postback_, but the server _must_ reload the javascript code because the values of charts may change _I'll edit the question adding this info_.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you shared an example of the generated JS, if any, that appears on the SharePoint page.

Comment: I'll add the sample js code, no problem. Editing...

Comment: Checked the actualization of your answer, I replaced the code with your suggestion code, but there's no results.

Comment: Could you try putting a `console.log("test");` in your script to see if it's being executed at all?  (Specifically in the `drawChart` function).

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome browser; I'm checking and see in "Elements" tab that when a postback occurs, the "pnl_data" is empty, I'm still testing and I'll put the console.log, but, What value I put on Console.log? only console.log("test")? _sorry, I didn't understand_.

Comment: Correct, just `console.log("test");` that will show up in your browser's console if it executes.  You can access the console in chrome by pressing F12 and hitting the last tab.

Comment: Sorry for reply late, with some adjustments to source code, I invoke the "GenerateChart()" in the "OnPreRender" method _without know if this is the best approach_ the generation of charts now works. "I suppose that, even when in Chrome console shows that the column or pie chart _code_ changes accordingly, it cannot render due to the code doesn't invoke again in the **OnPreRender** method", however, during this day I'll add the full answer "because I found that in IE doesn't show", but in F12 console tool, the **_IE7 standars_** shows the column chart correctly.
Thanks.